# Заполнение DatagridView из Массива объектов или коллекции

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

Имеется компонент `dataGridView` и массив\коллекция объектов. 
Как заполнить `dataGridView` из массива\коллекции объектов?

Такой способ не подходит, т.к. нужно делать поля открытыми.

```
for (int i = 0; i < employees.Count; i++) {
     dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[Column_SecondName].Value = employees[i].secondName;
 }
```

Существует ли способ заполнять `dataGridView` массивом\коллекцией объектов с закрытыми полями?

Comment: Не проще ли поля заменить на свойства и если тебе не хочется, что бы внешние объекты присваивали значения, пометить set как private?

Comment: Возможно и проще, но вот интересно, когда DataSource присвоили коллекцию, как сам dataGridView потом заполнить

Comment: Раз поля закрыты - значит так надо. Если не вы автор тех объектов, то забудьте про те поля, их нет. А если вы автор кода, то откройте их, тем или иным способом.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov т.е. вы хотите сказать, что если поля  закрыты, то datagridview заполнить коллекцией объектов нельзя?

Comment: Если поля закрыты, значит автор кода не хотел, чтобы к ним обращались напрямую.

Comment: это не ответ на последний вопрос

Comment: Через стандартную привязку - нельзя.

Answer (score 1):

Можно воспользоваться рефлексией и получить доступ к значениям, но на мой взгляд -это не верно.

Не проще ли заменить поля на свойства и set пометить, как private?

В таком случае внешние объекты смогут только читать данные, а присваивать не смогут.

Тогда справедлив код ниже:

У `DataGridView` есть свойство `DataSource`. Этому свойству присваивается коллекция, а потом `DataGridView` генерит столбцы и строки на основании данных в ней.

Comment: Как dataGridView генерит столбцы и строки? Я что-то не понимаю, после того, как коллекция присвоена dataSourse - dataGridView всё равно пустой

Comment: AutoGenerateColumns стоит в True?

Comment: Да, true, но у меня даже кол-во столбцов и строк известно, в dataGridView уже задано их количество, остается только лишь заполнить.